# Concatenate a list buffers in Node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer

I can't get work concatenation a list buffers.
I have different results with string and buffers and can't get a clue why this happened.

This is the sort of tiff algoritm. 
I iterate the lines and create array of hex that represent compressed line of the points:

line = ['00', 'FF', '1C', 'FF' ...]

and buffer

buf = <Buffer 00 FF 1C FF ... >

Rows have a different length, so I can't allocate buffer.

I recheck that rows generated with different approach are identical, so the error is in concatention metod:

line.join('') === buf.toString('hex')).toUpperCase()

Here is my code that works correctly:

```
 let blob = [];

 // create header
 blob.push(Buffer.from('554e495241535400', 'hex'));
 ... 
 //
 let lines = [];
 for (let y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    //
        ... calculate row
    //
    // make sure that string and buffer identical
    if (line.join('') !== ((buf.slice(0, marker)).toString('hex')).toUpperCase()) {
         console.log(line.join(''), ((buf.slice(0, marker)).toString('hex')).toUpperCase());
     } else {
         console.log('match');
     }
    // all lines match!
    // 
    if (y <= 2) {
         lines.push('00'); // packBit - next line
         lines.push(((buf.slice(0, marker)).toString('hex')).toUpperCase());
     } else if (lines[lines.length - 1] !== ((buf.slice(0, marker)).toString('hex')).toUpperCase() || parseInt(lines[lines.length - 2], 16) === 127) {
         lines.push('00'); // packBit - next line
         lines.push(((buf.slice(0, marker)).toString('hex')).toUpperCase());
     } else {
         lines[lines.length - 2] = hex(parseInt(lines[lines.length - 2], 16) + 1); // packBit - repeat last row n times
     }
 }
 blob.push(new Buffer(lines.join(''), 'hex')); // <- This works correctly
 callback(null, Buffer.concat(blob));
```

Now the same flow with buffer:

```
 let buf1 = []; // array of buffers
 let marker = 0; // last pos in line
 for (let y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    //
        ... calculate row
    //
    // make sure that string and buffer identical
    if (line.join('') !== ((buf.slice(0, marker)).toString('hex')).toUpperCase()) {
         console.log(line.join(''), ((buf.slice(0, marker)).toString('hex')).toUpperCase());
     } else {
         console.log('match');
     }
    //
    if (y <= 2) {
         buf1.push(Buffer.from('00', 'hex')); // packBit - next line
         buf1.push(buf.slice(0, marker));
     } else if (buf1[buf1.length - 1] !== buf.slice(0, marker) || buf1[buf1.length - 2][0] > 126) {
         buf1.push(Buffer.from('00', 'hex')); // packBit - next line
         buf1.push(buf.slice(0, marker));
     } else {
         buf1[buf1.length - 2][0]++; // packBit - repeat last row n times
     }
 }
 blob.push(Buffer.concat(buf1)); // <- here we have error
 callback(null, Buffer.concat(blob));
```

The result of this does not match the previous flow.

The size of buffers is identical and most of the lines matching. But some bytes inside buffer has different values.